# How do I install kbuild?

Tags: python

How do I run/install this: https://github.com/kevmoo/kbuild?

I installed the dependencies and tried to execute the bin/kbuild Python script, but it's giving me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "kbuild/bin/kbuild", line 12, in <module>
    BREW_PREFIX = subprocess.check_output(['brew', '--prefix']).strip()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 537, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1259, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

My guess is that this tool was intended for OSX and Homebrew and that's why it's choking.  I just wasn't sure based on the minimalist installation instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the `kbuild` script it does appear to be OS X & `brew` specific.

- https://github.com/kevmoo/kbuild/blob/master/bin/kbuild

*excerpt from script*

```
...
BREW_PREFIX = subprocess.check_output(['brew', '--prefix']).strip()
compiler_search_path = path.join(BREW_PREFIX, 'Cellar/closure-compiler', '*', 'libexec/build/compiler.jar')
compilers = glob.glob(compiler_search_path)
...
```

The [`homebrew` directory on github](https://github.com/kevmoo/kbuild/tree/master/homebrew) would seem to lead credence to this too:

> If you'd like to install kbuild via Homebrew:
>
> brew install https://raw.github.com/kevmoo/homebrew-kevmoo/master/kbuild.rb
>
> or
>
> brew tap brew tap kevmoo/kevmoo brew install kbuild